# ListView select and deselect on click (no Ctrl + click needed)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-10, uwp

Normal ListView in UWP (with SelectionMode="Single") selects item when you click it and deselects item when you Ctrl + click it.

I want to change the deselect functionality so that you do not need to press Ctrl to deselect item. Just click selected item again to remove selection.

It seems that when setting SelectionMode="Multiple", clicking item again deselects it like I wanted but I do not want to get multiple items selected.

**UPDATE**

This is how im doing right now. So I'm listening SelectionChanged event, and when event is fired, im getting the selected item from ListView selectedItem property.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Cars}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CarSelectedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ICar">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I found a way answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458244/unselect-gridview-item-on-click-if-already-selected/34478110#34478110. Curious because I did not that ctrl-click worked to deselect

Comment: Added example to question how im doing right now. Based on your link, maybe I need to try to do this using ItemClick event?

Answer (score 1):

Enable IsItemClickEnabled in the Listview. When it is fired check whether the item clicked is already selected and deselect it. I have tested it and the click event occurs before the selection so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same issue, but in WPF. The solution could be compatible for UWP as well.

XAML:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="_ListViewSelectionChanged">
```

C#:

```
private void _ListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = (ListView)sender;
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && listView.SelectedItem != e.AddedItems[0])
        listView.SelectedItem = e.AddedItems[0];
}
```

The `Multiple` selection mode already deselects the selected item if it's clicked, you only need to worry about deselecting it if a different item gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

Set multiple SelectionMode and hide selection checkboxes

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="_listView_SelectionChanged" >
```

This event will be raised twice for every selection

```
Item prevSelection = null;
    private void _listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item selected = null;
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            selected = item as Item;
        }
        if (selected != null && selected != prevSelection)
        {
            prevSelection = selected;
            _listView.DeselectRange(new ItemIndexRange(0, (uint)_collection.Count));
            _listView.SelectedItem = selected; //will rise event again
            selected = prevSelection = null;
        }
    }
```